# Creating 3d text above an object in three js

Tags: javascript, three.js, 3d

I have 3D model which I have created in three.js. Based on some data, I want to create a text above each object of my scene.

It seems like I have one option which is creating a 3d text model and position it above my object , but this doesn't work with me i don't know if i had commited an error or something like that.

I'm wondering how to go about this. Which is the "correct" way to do this? Any suggestions and example code is very welcome!

[here is my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gVRpN.png)

[here is my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AL39T.png)

Comment: You could use CSS2D: https://threejs.org/examples/?q=label#css2d_label It's simpler than having to create, position, and rotate 3D geometries.

Comment: that's what i am loolking for , thank you a lot